# Calculate rate constant of second order reaction and pseudo first order reaction

Tags: concentration, rate-equation, reaction-order

> The reaction A + B -> Prod follows the second order kinetics. In an experiment, you initially have ten times as much B
> as A. The concentration of A varies with time according to the following data:
>
> [image]
>
> How big will the error in the determined rate constant be if you choose to analyze the reaction as a pseudo-1st?

I began by plotting the first order reaction for this problem as ln[A] against t. From this I got that the slope = -$9.06 * 10^{-4}$ s$^{-1}$ and so the rate constant is k$_1$ =  $9.06 * 10^{-4}$ s$^{-1}$.

However, I am having trouble understanding how to plot for the second order reaction. I know that I should plot ln(a-x)/(b-x) but I don't understand how this is gotten from the given data.

How can I determine (a-x) and (b-x)?

I thought that x = [A]$_0$ - [A]$_t$ = $0.01$ - $1.11*10^{-6}$ = $0.0099$. But then do I subtract that from all the given data points? I did this and it gives me negative values and then I can't do the natural log in order to plot the points. Also if x = $0.0099$ and b = $10$*[A)$_0$ = $0.1$ then I get that (b-x) = $0.0901$ for all the points?

Comment: Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic expressions and keeping it this way until all is ready to plug in literal numbers. Advantage is: Focus on principles, Easier spotting of mistakes, Improved orientation, Q/A reusability and the permanent value. 

You may find useful  [formatting mathematical/chemical expressions/formulas](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88).

Answer (score 1):

The general rate law for a second order kinetics if $\pu{A_o < B_o}$, is $$\pu{\frac{1}{B_o - A_o} \ln\frac{A_o B}{A B_o} = kt}$$ If you only want to check that it is second oder, you can forget about the constants $\pu{A_o}$ and $\pu{B_o}$, and plot the logarithm of $\pu{\frac{B}{A}}$ versus the time $t$. The points should be well alined if it is second order.

Ref. Arthur A. Frost, Ralph G. Pearson, Kinetics and Mechanism, J. Wiley, NY, 1965, p. 16.